# Templated correspondence generation using Java

Tags: java, pdf-generation, itext, web, birt

I am looking for a way to create pixel perfect, paginated, styled correspondence in a Java web application.

The requirements for this functionality are
 - Ability to define outer/ master template with header/ footer/ logo etc...
 - Ability to define inner content template where specific variables/ fields can be substituted with instance values at run time - e.g. employeeName. employeeAddress. The content template would be defined online using rich text editor or something similar
 - Supports tables/ list

I believe iText does most/ if not all. Other options that I have considered is BIRT. Are there other/ better choices for this purpose?

Thanks

Comment: Any PDF solution will certainly be pixel-perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done something like with iText, although our case did not use an online text editor (we had a small number of templates and they were defined as part of the development cycle)

[Note: We did this under an older version of iText when it was still LGPL rather than Affero GPL]

The results were excellent, but in order to get it pixel-perfect we had to do a lot of work ourselves. We did manual layout and pagination - including manual text wrapping, etc. The layout tools that iText provides looked good, but they didn't give us the pixel-perfect control that we needed for the use case we had.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [iReport](http://jasperforge.org/projects/ireport).

Comment: Isn't JasperSoft license similar to iText - i.e. if your product (yes, ours is a product - not an internal application) is not open source then you need a commercial license?

Comment: It may be, but we used an older version (~ version 2.0 iirc) so licensing may have been different back then?